# Blender glitchy animation export fbx UE4

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, bones

I'm trying very basic stuff here.

I have made a running animation on a armature rigged soldier model. The animation plays all fine in blender , but glitches out a horrible mess after export to UE4 as FBX.

All IK bones (colored sticks) are orphans and have unchecked Deform option

I have tried this like 50 times in last 4 days with different animations, Some time some animations will work and some time they suddenly start to glitch if I make a change and some are just already glitched. However inside Blender They all work fine

**Animation in blender**

[image]

**Aniation in UE4**

[image]

**Export settings for Mesh**

[image]

**Export settings for Animation**

[image]

**observed points:**

1.The animation worked fine earlier when I exported it halfway in its making to test.

2.It looks like the action editor may be responsible as sometimes cleaning all keyframes and making a new animation from scratch fixes it but this is not feasible.

3.This mostly happens if I change any keyframe (like move a bone and replace the keyframe with that pose using I key)

([Attached .blend and texture file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5rd4cfqsqn7vm3d/anim.zip?dl=0/))

Comment: No one has a clue?

Comment: This is a known issue with FBX exported by Blender and UE4, investigated since months now… :/ See https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/98704/fbx-import-wrong-application-of-animations-to-bone.html

Comment: @user1062760 is it possible that i have the same problem:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122689/weird-bone-axis-rotation-problems-from-blender-to-ue4/122690#122690 ?