# weird bone axis/rotation problems (from blender to UE4)

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, unreal-engine, axis

i'm quite new, to unreal engine en blender. (installed both 1,5 month ago)
and i start working on my first game/interactive experience.
and i have run in a lot of problems sinds ;p (of course ;))
but now i have this problem where i can't find a solution to.
i'm not quit sure of the problem is in blender or its a problem in the unreal editor.
so i hope you guys can help me out with this one. :)
here i have a download link to this pictures, blender file & the fbx file: https://we.tl/t-0vUF3JDmJz

so here the problem:
i have made this model in blender (image 1A):
[image]

a skeleton and a animation with it (image 1B):
[image]

witchs i wanted it to import into UE4, and at the first sight, everything lookt alright (image 2A):
[image]

but as soon as i start the animation, things started to look really weird (image 3A, 3B & 3C):

[image]

[image]

[image]

i think UE4 or blender has done something really weird with the axis of my bones.
and if i take a look at the skeleton tab, i think i can see the axis's of my bones (or the bones them self) out of place (image 4A & 4B):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

so i went back in blender to check de axis from my bones and meshes, and as far as i can see the axis's for the bones and meshes are there perfectly in place (as it should be, because of using the "shift+s" methode) (image 5A & 5B):
[image]

[image]

i have searched a lot on the internet but unfortunately i can't find the solution for this problem.. :|
and i really running out of options here.. :(

I'm using: windows 7, blender 2.80 & unreal editor 4.20.3

so if you know a solution, please tell me! ;D
really big thanks already for reading and thinking! ;)
gr grover

PS: i'm from the netherlands and i'm really bad at speaking and especially writting english, so srry if i made this hard to read! ;)